# How Do i get value Of name='blur' From html Form in My Laravel Controller

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-9

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;
class IamgesController extends Controller
{
public function uploadimage(Request $request)
{
    $imagefile=$request->photo;
    if($imagefile!=null){
        $image=$request->file('photo');
        $filename=time().'.'.$request->photo->extension();
        $imageResize=Image::make($image->getRealPath());
        $blurvalue= **Here I want To Get A Numeric Value From HTML FORM**           
        $imageResize->blur($blurvalue);
        $imageResize->save(public_path($filename));
        echo "<img src='".$filename."'>";
    }

}
}
```

I Am A NewBie In Laravel,
I want To Get value from HTML Form IN my Controller, I tried Many Solution But None of any is working.

Comment: You have tagged it both versions 5 & 8, which version are you using?

Comment: laravel 9 I Am Using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTTP Requests in Laravel Document](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests)

**HTML Form**:

```
<input name="blur">
```

**Laravel Controller** :

```
public function uploadimage(Request $request)
{
    //get blur input value
    $blurValue = $request->blur;
...
```

`return $request->all();` return all inputs values